# Please choose a font with a more distinctive 0 (zero)

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, css

math.stackexchange.com has handsome CSS styling, but 0 (zero) and o (lowercase O) are visually nearly indistinguishable.  That's ironic for a math forum (n0)?

I'd suggest using a font that features a distinctive zero.

(meta meta question: Am I the only one that's bugged by this?  I didn't see other meta questions on this.)  Update: [anorton](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/23353/anorton) correctly points out that there has been discussion on using "non-lining" digits in [Why does the font use text figures (“lowercase digits”)?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/why-does-the-font-use-text-figures-lowercase-digits).

Comment: I think rendering 0 in $\LaTeX$ is a good idea here. It renders as $0$ which is distinctly different from o, O, $o$ and $O$. Whenever writing any numbers in a math paper or here on MSE, I always put it in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10317/23353

Comment: @CameronWilliams For a math paper, the difference is extremely minute with default fonts (Latin Modern). [Comparison](https://i.imgur.com/4NvyBRj.png): I'm not even sure I can see it or if I'm imagining it. But here on MSE that's much more important: 0$0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams this might be a personal stylistic choice yet is not recommended practice in general.

Comment: Oh wait. You're right. I *used* to put numbers in LaTeX in papers until I noticed exactly what you just did. However I do put numbers in LaTeX here.

Comment: Do you have a genuine example where this could cause any confusion, actually?

Comment: I thought that $0$ and o are quite distinct up until now. Or do you want to insist not to use MathJax for writing mathematics in a clear way, and just complain about it?

Comment: apparently CSS is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: One example: "x ranges from t0 to t1".  Another (which prompted me to create this post): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122094/trying-to-define-a-simple-warp-function.  As an aside, I'm proud that every meta stack exchange post I've made has ended up getting me negative points.  :)

Comment: @fearless_fool: The first should be written as "$x$ ranges from $t_0$ to $t_1$."  Similarly, you can use dollar signs in the post you linked to to improve readability, including but not only for the numbers.

Comment: @fearless_fool I said a genuine example. If you're too lazy to use mathjax when it's clearly warranted, that's your fault, not SE's fault. And even without mathjax your post wasn't confusing... And I don't really understand what kind of pride you can take in people disagreeing with you.

Comment: @CameronWilliams you could write a whole question self answer thread on academia stack exchange just based off this comment. It might even be useful for people new to the field.

Answer (score 6):

When writing I try to follow 3 rules. If followed, your 0 vs o is not an issue.

1. Use math mode for maths. For example, if I have $10$ orangutangs and I buy $32$ more then I have $42$ orangutangs.
2. Spell out the numbers for small numbers. For example, "follow three rules" but not "follow thirty-three rules". (The first journal I submitted to stipulated that I do this, and I have done so ever since.)
3. Use the normal numbers the rest of the time. For example, I bought lots of orangutangs in January 2015.

A related TeX.SE answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38827/13669). Notably, this answer includes the a quote from Donald Knuth (the man behind $\TeX$).

> The following is an excerpt from Knuth's article ["Typesetting Concrete Mathematics"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38827/13669) (TUGBoat, 1989) [Aside: The textbook *Concrete Mathematics* was typeset using `Concrete Roman` as the text font and `Euler` as the math font]:
>
> There was, however, one significant  difference between  typing the manuscripts for *Concrete Mathematics* and for  *The Art of Computer Programming*, caused by the fact that the  Euler numerals  $0123456789$  are  distinctly different from the numerals 0123456789 in ordinary text.  [...]
> This experience ... taught me that there  is  a useful  and meaningful  distinction between  text  numerals and mathematical numerals. Text  numerals  are  used  in  contexts like  '1776'  and  'Chapter  5'  and  '41 ways', where  the numbers  are  essentially  part of the English language; mathematical numerals, by  contrast,  are
> used in contexts like 'the greatest common divisor of $12$ and $18$ is $6$',  where the  numbers are part of  the mathematics. [...]
> Equation numbers presented us with one of the most perplexing  design  questions.  Should  those numbers be typeset in Euler or cast in Concrete?  After several experiments we  hit on a solution that must  be right,  because it seems so obvious in retrospect:  We  decided  to  set equation numbers  in  an "oldstyle"  variant  of  Concrete  Roman ...

---

Interestingly, I notice when typing this answer that the typefaces are different for typing and for reading - the typing typeface has a [slashed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashed_zero), which is designed to get rid of the ambiguity you mention.

Comment: "the typing typeface has a slashed zero"  -- exactly my point.  if I was writing a technical paper, then sure, I'd use TeX.  But MS should be a place where it's easy to pose a question.  Why should the choice of font force you to drop into TeX every time you want to write a number?

Comment: The typeface for composing a question/answer/comment has a slashed zero because when you're composing something, there is no formatting, so *if* you are typing code, math... then the font should be unambiguous, because the formatting won't be able to help you. But once you've submitted it, your submission is properly formatted so that's not important anymore. The typeface for composing is also fixed-width, for example, but only code blocks are fixed-width once submitted. And anyway I have yet to see a single instance of 0/o ambiguity causing a problem on MSE.

Comment: @fearless_fool *"Why should the choice of font force you to drop into TeX every time you want to write a number?"* A similar question, but in terms of StackOverflow, would be "why make me super-indent my code to make it have a grey background and syntax highlighting?  StackOverflow should be a place where it's easy to ask a question, and I shouldn't have to implement code-format syntax to post my question."  A necessary step in attaining the goal of being "expert community" is having high-quality questions.  High quality questions need proper formatting.

Comment: @fearless_fool to put those numbers that are part of the mathematical content in math-mode conveys  semantic information. You should thus do this regardless of the look of the figures.